# MacOS Mojave doesn't give IP for Internet Sharing

Tags: macos, network, wifi, mojave, internet-sharing

I'm trying to share the internet connection from a MBP with an Android phone or Windows laptop.

Right now, the MBP gets internet from another Android phone (USB tethering + HoRNDIS) and I want to share it over wifi. The internet works on MBP, but when I try to connect to wifi, it shows *Obtaining IP address...*, but without success.

The internet connection looks like this:

[image]

And this is how it looks the **ifconfig** result (when sharing is enabled):

```
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 16384
    options=1203<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TXSTATUS,SW_TIMESTAMP>
    inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000 
    inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 
    inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
gif0: flags=8010<POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST> mtu 1280
stf0: flags=0<> mtu 1280
XHC20: flags=0<> mtu 0
XHC0: flags=0<> mtu 0
XHC1: flags=0<> mtu 0
VHC128: flags=0<> mtu 0
en5: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether ac:de:48:00:11:22 
    inet6 fe80::aede:48ff:fe00:1122%en5 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x8 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect (100baseTX <full-duplex>)
    status: active
ap1: flags=8943<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether 3a:f9:d3:51:c5:8c 
    media: autoselect
    status: active
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether 38:f9:d3:51:c5:8c 
    inet6 fe80::4be:76df:8637:b5c3%en0 prefixlen 64 secured scopeid 0xa 
    inet 169.254.1.183 netmask 0xffff0000 broadcast 169.254.255.255
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect (<unknown type>)
p2p0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 2304
    ether 0a:f9:d3:51:c5:8c 
    media: autoselect
    status: inactive
awdl0: flags=8943<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1484
    ether 1e:e2:1e:18:70:26 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect
    status: inactive
en1: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=60<TSO4,TSO6>
    ether de:00:e0:20:71:01 
    media: autoselect <full-duplex>
    status: inactive
en2: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=60<TSO4,TSO6>
    ether de:00:e0:20:71:00 
    media: autoselect <full-duplex>
    status: inactive
en3: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=60<TSO4,TSO6>
    ether de:00:e0:20:71:05 
    media: autoselect <full-duplex>
    status: inactive
en4: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=60<TSO4,TSO6>
    ether de:00:e0:20:71:04 
    media: autoselect <full-duplex>
    status: inactive
bridge0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=63<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TSO4,TSO6>
    ether de:00:e0:20:71:04 
    Configuration:
        id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 hellotime 0 fwddelay 0
        maxage 0 holdcnt 0 proto stp maxaddr 100 timeout 1200
        root id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 ifcost 0 port 0
        ipfilter disabled flags 0x2
    member: en4 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 16 priority 0 path cost 0
    member: en3 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 15 priority 0 path cost 0
    member: en2 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 14 priority 0 path cost 0
    member: en1 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 13 priority 0 path cost 0
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: <unknown type>
    status: inactive
utun0: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 2000
    inet6 fe80::742:c55e:e28b:11bf%utun0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x12 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
en6: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether 02:57:52:54:34:32 
    inet6 fe80::c1e:4b6:50f8:bc23%en6 prefixlen 64 secured scopeid 0x13 
    inet 192.168.42.89 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.42.255
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
bridge100: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=3<RXCSUM,TXCSUM>
    ether ae:de:48:00:33:64 
    inet 192.168.2.1 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.2.255
    inet6 fe80::acde:48ff:fe00:3364%bridge100 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x14 
    Configuration:
        id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 hellotime 0 fwddelay 0
        maxage 0 holdcnt 0 proto stp maxaddr 100 timeout 1200
        root id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 ifcost 0 port 0
        ipfilter disabled flags 0x2
    member: ap1 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 9 priority 0 path cost 0
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
```

I searched for different solutions on Google, but none of them seems to be solve the problem.

Comment: Are you certain a internet sharing is enabled?  It appears that WiFi has a self assigned IP which indicates it’s not enabled.   Out of curiosity, why aren’t you just using the Android as a hotspot and connect everything to that?  This seems overly complex

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem, it was the firewall from McAfee that was blocking the Internet Sharing.